# How to Hide Calendar Header (calendarHeaderComponent) in Mat Date Picker

Tags: angular-material

I have added a date Picker:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pad-20">
        <mat-label>Monthly Scheduling Day</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="monthlyDateFilter" [matDatepicker]="testPicker"
          (dateChange)="onDateSelectionChange('Monthly', $event)" onkeypress="return false;"
          [formControl]="monthlyDatePickerForm">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="testPicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #testPicker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
```

And I do not want the Calendar header component

[image]

It should somewhat looks like the below image

[image]

What option I could use to get that working.